# NSFetchedResultsController With Core Data on a background thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am aware there are lots of questions relating to this already on Stack Overflow. I have tried various methods and I am now in a situation where i'm not even sure whats right and whats not :S

I have a fairly standard problem, I want Core Data on a separate thread to be updating and the UI (tableview) to be updated as records are updated / added.

From my understanding I need to have two instances of my NSManagedObjectContext

So I have setup my AppDelegate methods as such:

```
 lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator == nil {
            return nil
        }
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "contextDidSave:", name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: nil)
        return managedObjectContext
        }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    func contextDidSave(notification: NSNotification){
        let sender = notification.object as! NSManagedObjectContext
        if sender !== self.managedObjectContext{
            self.managedObjectContext!.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
        }
    }
```

Now at the minute the application falls over when it reaches this line

```
 self.managedObjectContext!.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
```

My view controller is setup as follows:

```
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
        let workFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Work")
        let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdDate", ascending: true)
        let secondarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "town", ascending: true)
        workFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor, secondarySortDescriptor]

        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: workFetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!,
            sectionNameKeyPath: "createdDate",
            cacheName: nil)

        frc.delegate = self

        return frc
        }()


    // MARK: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods
     func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tblJobs.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(
        controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject,
        atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
        newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

            switch type {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:

                if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                    self.tblJobs.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
                }
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:

                if let deleteIndexPath = indexPath {
                    self.tblJobs.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([deleteIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
                }
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:

                if let updateIndexPath = indexPath {
                    let cell =  self.tblJobs.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
                        "JobCell", forIndexPath: updateIndexPath)
                        as! JobTableViewCell

                    let workItem = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(updateIndexPath) as? Work

                    cell.lblAddress1?.text = workItem!.propertyName + " "  + workItem!.propertyNumber + " " + workItem!.street
                    cell.lblAddress2?.text = workItem!.town + " " + workItem!.locality + " " + workItem!.postcode
                }
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:

                if let deleteIndexPath = indexPath {
                    self.tblJobs.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([deleteIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
                }


                if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                    self.tblJobs.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
                }
            }
    }

     func controller(
        controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo,
        atIndex sectionIndex: Int,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

            switch type {
            case .Insert:
                let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
                self.tblJobs.insertSections(sectionIndexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            case .Delete:
                let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
                self.tblJobs.deleteSections(sectionIndexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            default:
                ""
            }
    }
```

Again, I'm not sure if the way I am calling the managedObjectContext is correct here.

And finally my networking class, I realise a lot of this needs abstracting out but I just wanted the thing to work first. Note thatI am using dispatch_async to utilise a separate thread, everything relating to using multi threads pointed to using this but now i am not sure if it is needed in the context of using NSManagedObjectContext

```
let lockQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.app.LockQueue", nil)
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

func makeRequest(url : String, params : [String : String]?, completionHandler: (responseObject: JSON?, error: NSError?) -> ())  -> Request? {

    return Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: params, encoding: .URL)
        .responseString { request, response, responseBody, error in completionHandler(
            responseObject:
            {
                // JSON to return
                var json : JSON?

                if let response = responseBody {
                    // Parse the response to NSData
                    if let data = (response as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                        json = JSON(data: data)
                    }
                }

                return json

                }(), error: error)
    }
}

func fetchItems(completion: (NSError?) -> Void) {
    self.makeRequest("http://localhost/jobs.json", params: nil) { json, error  in

        var tempContext: NSManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
        tempContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext


            tempContext.performBlock({

                dispatch_async(self.lockQueue) {


                    let entity = "Work"

                    if let obj = json {

                        for (index, object) in obj {

                                var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
                                request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", object["Id"].stringValue)
                                var error: NSError?
                                if let entities = tempContext.executeFetchRequest(
                                    request,
                                    error: &error
                                    ) as? [NSManagedObject] {
                                        if entities.count != 0{
                                            println("found an existing record...")
                                            for entity in entities {
                                                                                                  /*TODO: Change this to call an external function to update all entities*/
                                                entity.setValue(object["Town"].stringValue, forKey: "Town")

                                            }

                                            tempContext.save(nil)
                                        }else{
                                            println("Creating a new entity")

                                            Work.createInManagedObjectContext(tempContext,
                                                id: object["Id"].stringValue,
                                                flatNumber: object["FlatNumber"].stringValue,
                                                propertyName: object["PropertyName"].stringValue,
                                                propertyNumber: object["PropertyNumber"].stringValue,
                                                street: object["Street"].stringValue,
                                                locality: object["Locality"].stringValue,
                                                town: object["Town"].stringValue,
                                                postcode: object["Postcode"].stringValue,
                                                createdDate: object["CreatedDate"].stringValue

                                            )

                                        }
                                }

                            if !tempContext.save(&error) {
                                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
                                abort()

                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

                var error: NSError? = nil
                if tempContext.hasChanges && !tempContext.save(&error) {
                    NSLog("error: %@\n UserInfo: %@\n", error!, error!.userInfo!)
                }
                else {
                    println("Error?")
                }

            })

        completion(error)

    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the app isn't saving records, and it falls over randomly when it is inserting them (i'm trying to replicate this circumstance and i'll update with some further info) and when I am updating the tableview I can see that the background operation is running but the table just isn't updating.

I realised another user had a similar problem and it turned out to be more of an issue with his NSFetchedResultsController. But I have a feeling my background thread isn't setup properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create your own queue and dispatch to it. By calling `tempContext.performBlock` you're asking the context to perform an operation on its own background queue for you. So, when you dispatch inside that block you're breaking your contract.

You also don't need the notification and merging as you are setting the parent to your main thread context so changes will be saved up automatically. However, when you have saved the temp context you do then need to save the main context as it will be dirty with the changes you just made (and this is what actually saves the data to the persistent store and therefore to disk).

When triggering the main context save you should do it inside a `performBlockAndWait:` if you're going to match each of your batched save operations.

Comment: how do i save the mainContext when the tempContext has been saved?

Comment: just `managedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait({managedObjectContext.save...})`

Comment: sorry, i meant to ask where / when, i have added it after the tempContext.perform block but its still not persisting

Comment: That would be after each save in the temp performBlock. How are you testing the persistence, and is the FRC getting the updates?

Comment: i added it in like so: tempContext.save(nil)
                                                self.managedObjectContext!.performBlockAndWait({
                                                    managedObjectContext!.save
                                                })
I'm testing the persistence by manually stopping the app and loading it again. aaand no it doesnt look like my frc is gettingthe updates...

Comment: I am having a similar problem and I can tell my FRC is not being updated when the context is saved, but I'm not sure how to solve it.  The changes are being persisted to Core Data but the fetched results controller is never updated with the changes.  How did you ultimately solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass a NSManagedObjectContext when registering for context did save notification.

```
var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "contextDidSave:", name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: managedObjectContext)
```

Edit :
The problem is also that you are registering for context did save and you merge changes with the same context you registered for (self.managedObjectContext)

Comment: I already have this code present in my  lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {} in app delegate, do you mean putting it inside the contextDidSave  function?

Comment: No no, look at `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "contextDidSave:", name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: managedObjectContext)` you put `nil` for `object` parameter

Comment: thanks, but as pointed out i dont need that bit so i've commented out the contextDidSave and merge changes bits.